# how to give a custom name for lighthouse report which is generated by cypress-audit package

Tags: javascript, cypress, lighthouse, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-task

I need to generate multiple lighthouse reports for multiple test scenarios. by using cypress-audit package I wrote a method for generating lighthouse report.

in below you can see that method

```
export function lighthouseAudit(scenarioId, baseValueData) {
    const lighthouseMetrics = {
        performance: baseValueData.performance,
        accessibility: baseValueData.accessibility,
        seo: baseValueData.seo,
        pwa: baseValueData.pwa
    };

    cy.log("lighthousemetrics", lighthouseMetrics);

    const desktopConfig = {
        formFactor: 'desktop',
        screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
    };

    cy.lighthouse(lighthouseMetrics, desktopConfig);
}
```

below you can see how I generated the report once after called "lighthouseAudit" method

```
//cypress.config.js file
    module.exports = defineConfig({
      reporter: 'mochawesome',
      defaultCommandTimeout: 6000,
      taskTimeout: 20000,
      execTimeout: 6000,
      viewportWidth: 1920,
      viewportHeight: 1080,
      e2e: {
        experimentalSessionAndOrigin:true,
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
          getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config);
          on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
          on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
            prepareAudit(launchOptions);
          });
          on('task', {
            lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
              const folderPathForLH = "cypress/lightHouse"
              if (!fs.existsSync(folderPathForLH)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(folderPathForLH);
              }
              fs.writeFileSync(`${folderPathForLH}/lightHouseReport.html`, ReportGenerator.generateReport(lighthouseReport.lhr, 'html'));
              return lighthouseReport;
            }),
          });
        },
        specPattern: "**/*.{feature,features}"
      },
    });
```

[image]

as you can see I gave the name as "lightHouseReport.html" for the report. but the issue is it will replace when each test ran. I want to create reports for each and every test.

[image]

when calling "lighthouseAudit" method I am passing "scenarioId" as a parameter. I want to create the lighthouse report by that name.

example

```
lighthouseAudit("storydashboard",baseValues);
```

output should be

```
"storydashboard.html"
```

used packages

```
  "@cypress-audit/lighthouse": "^1.3.1",
  "cypress": "^10.9.0",
  "cypress-audit": "^1.1.0",
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the simplest way would be to add another task that sends the name from the test into the node process.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
let lighthouseReportName;                          // add this to hold the name

module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  defaultCommandTimeout: 6000,
  taskTimeout: 20000,
  execTimeout: 6000,
  viewportWidth: 1920,
  viewportHeight: 1080,
  e2e: {
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin:true,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config);
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        prepareAudit(launchOptions);
      });
      on('task', {

        setLighthouseReportName: (name) => {             // called any time 
          lighthouseReportName = name                    // you want a new name
        }
       
        lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
          const folderPathForLH = "cypress/lightHouse"
          if (!fs.existsSync(folderPathForLH)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(folderPathForLH);
          }

          const filePath = `${folderPathForLH}/${lightHouseReportName}.html`

          fs.writeFileSync(filePath, 
            ReportGenerator.generateReport(lighthouseReport.lhr, 'html'));
          return lighthouseReport;
        }),
      });
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.{feature,features}"
  },
});
```

**Test helper function**

```js
export function lighthouseAudit(scenarioId, baseValueData) {
    const lighthouseMetrics = {
        performance: baseValueData.performance,
        accessibility: baseValueData.accessibility,
        seo: baseValueData.seo,
        pwa: baseValueData.pwa
    };

    cy.log("lighthousemetrics", lighthouseMetrics);

    const desktopConfig = {
        formFactor: 'desktop',
        screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
    };

    cy.task('setLighthouseReportName', scenarioId)   

    cy.lighthouse(lighthouseMetrics, desktopConfig);
}
```

Without looking into the code, I presume that `cy.lighthouse()` will internally call the task `lighthouse` without your intervention.

Since there's some asynchronous actions going on, you may need to sequence the `setLighthouseReportName` task and the subsequent report like this

```js
cy.task('setLighthouseReportName', scenarioId)  
  .then(() => {
    cy.lighthouse(lighthouseMetrics, desktopConfig);
  })
```